# Cassandra Storm Integration

Tags: cassandra, apache-storm

I was looking into the Storm-Cassandra Example to build on a solution for my application. 
From the examples in https://github.com/hmsonline/storm-cassandra

I find that the tuples and declarer of the bolt which emits to the cassandra bolt is of a specific fashion:
The column names are declared as a constant string by the Outputdeclarer of the bolt which emits to the cassandra bolt.

Is there any work around this? Pointers to other examples where I can take a leaf from would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: The storm-cassandra library available in github is based on Astyanax client. So my question is do you want to go with Astyanax or you have any other choices in your mind?

Comment: I think you should post this question here: https://github.com/hmsonline/storm-cassandra/issues

Comment: I was experimenting with Hector when I came across this project where an api was already available. I find it using Astyanax but the api seems to be quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this one a try:
[LINK](https://github.com/tjake/stormscraper)